# how to execute code when apple watch is in sleep mode

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch

I have wrote a app on apple watch,but I found that I called sendMessage:replyHandler:, I couldn't receive a replyHandler after apple watch going sleep. How I should do?

Answer (score 0):

That's right, so `sendMessage:replyHandler:` is specifically use for the live communication so you can't use that but instead you can use **Update application contexts** or **Transfer user info and manage the outstanding transfers** functions to send data to your watch app from the iOS app.

Comment: how can I use it ? Can u provide a example code? Thank you very much !

Comment: You can check this source code from [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/using_watch_connectivity_to_communicate_between_your_apple_watch_app_and_iphone_app) that should help you.

Comment: Sorry, It's doesn't work when apple watch in sleep mode when wrist lower the watch